# how should position: fixed work in a shadow DOM root?

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

I have a div with `position: fixed`, which hypothetically should attach to the bottom of the viewport and not scroll, at least according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Instead, what I get is a div that is stuck in its initial position (the bottom of the viewport when the page is rendered), but then scrolls up and down with the shadow-dom scroller.

EDIT:

Here's a codepen with the element inside the core-scaffold. Note that the red div in this pen has position: fixed as described in my code below.

http://codepen.io/ericeslinger/pen/bdedgp

Here's a codepen with the element outside the core-scaffold. This is the behavior I'd like to have, but with the div structurally inside the core-scaffold (for angular scoping reasons).

http://codepen.io/ericeslinger/pen/jPrPyy

FWIW, I'm using polymer 0.5. Here's a sketch of what I'm running:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.testClass {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body unresolved>
<core-scaffold>
  <div main vertical layout>
    <span>woo</span>
    <div class="testClass">This is some stuff at the bottom</div>
    <div style="min-height: 2000px" flex></div>
  </div>
</core-scaffold>
```

If I move the testClass div outside of core-scaffold, it does the expected thing and sticks to the bottom of the window. If I keep it inside of core-scaffold, it doesn't.

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think so - I haven't seen any working polymer fiddles, plunks, codepens, or what have you: they have issues with CORS and CDNs, apparently. I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: Aha, I figured it out on codepen. Seems to work, or at least it works for me.

Answer (score 10):

This is probably not the answer to your question. But I had a similar issue with fixed position inside of Shadow DOM. I expected all elements to be inside of their parent div, but instead elements with position fixed were positioned relative to the browser viewport.
My solution was to add a dummy transform property so that all elements with fixed position got attached to their parent div.

```
#shadow-root (open)
<div style="transform: scale(1);">
 /* my shadow root content here */
 <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0">this is now relative to parent div</div>
</div>
```

For reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Comment: What sorcery is this?

Comment: The reason why it works is described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values:~:text=It%20is%20positioned%20relative%20to%20the%20initial%20containing%20block%20established%20by%20the%20viewport%2C%20except%20when%20one%20of%20its%20ancestors%20has%20a%20transform%2C%20perspective%2C%20or%20filter%20property%20set%20to%20something%20other%20than%20none

Comment: @AnastasiiaSolop Hi! Please correct me if I'm wrong , but is this dependant on being encapsulated by a shadow root (because from what I've tried it does not seem so). Thanks !

Comment: yes, so inside of shadow root, you should create an element with style="transform: scale(1);", then you can put the rest of content inside and fixed position will be relative to the elements with transform

Comment: I ended up here looking for a solution to limit fixed elements inside of certain container. This solution made me look into shadow dom, which was not necessary for me at all. Solution for me was to use that `style="transform: scale(1);"` in my root element and ignore the shadow dom part completely. I'll leave this comment here if someone else is also looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

The codepen links in the original question are not working:

> Access to imported resource at 'https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html' from origin 'https://s.codepen.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I was trying to get a better understanding about `position:fixed` and `Shadow DOM`. I was hoping that `position:fixed` will be within the `Shadow DOM` boundary, not the viewport. Here is a demo I came up with:

```js
(function() {
 const template = document.createElement('template');

 template.innerHTML = `
 <style>
   :host {
    display: block;
     background: red;
   }
 </style>

 <div>
   <slot name="top"></slot>
   <hr>
   <slot name="bottom"></slot>
  </div>
 `;

 class MyInfoBox extends HTMLElement {
 constructor() {
   super();

   this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
   this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
 }
 }

 window.customElements.define('my-info-box', MyInfoBox);
})();
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<my-info-box>
 <span slot="top">TOP</span>
 <span slot="bottom">
  <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0">BOTTOM</div>
 </span>
</my-info-box>
```

Hope that helps (my future self). Sorry if I cannot be more specific about Polymer and core-scaffold. I don't really understand why web components are so niche and React is so everywhere de-facto a new web standard.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the question I asked is from four years ago. That polymer 0.5 context is pretty out of date, which is probably why it wouldn't load.

Comment: You are 100%, there was no need for mention a thing that does not work. The answer was mostly for me and my future self as I'm trying to get **Shadow DOM** to work :)